# Kubernetes exec script after helm upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, events, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to execute some code in pod containers when config maps are updated via helm. Preferrably without a custom sidecar doing constant file watching?

I am thinking along the lines of postStart and preExit lifecycle events of Kubernetes, but in my case a "postPatch".

Answer (score 1):

This might be something a `post-install` or `post-upgrade` hook would be perfect for:

https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

You can trigger these jobs to start after an install (`post-install`) and/or after an upgrade (`post-upgrade`) and they will run to completion before the chart is considered installed or upgraded.

So you can to the upgrade, then as part of that upgrade, the hook would trigger after the update and run your update code. I know the [nginx ingress controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start) chart does something like this.

Comment: As I understand post-install runs a Kubernetes 'Job' in a separate container. What I need is to execute code in the context of the already running container that was updated.

Comment: Yes, a hook will run as a separate job. If this doesn't suit your situation, another option would be to run an init container to check if it needs to run the script, then run it, before starting the main container. But then you need to be careful about running multiple copies of that script concurrently, since this would be the same for all other replicas in the deployment

Comment: The main container is not restarted during a swap of config maps. No init container runs.

Comment: You *could* an Admission Webhook to watch for the configmap change in the namespace, and then use the webhook container to `kubectl exec` into the pod(s) and run the code there.